# Is Magento 1.x knowledge required to get started with magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento2

I don't have any prior knowledge of Magento 1 or 2. I want to get started with magento 2. But the issue is magento 2 documentation seems not for magento beginners. Please can someone tell me if I need to learn magento 1 before getting started with magento 2?

Comment: Try this You will get some idea http://www.maximehuran.fr/en/magento-2-training-2/

Answer (score 3):

Understanding of Magento 1 is very helpful for Magento 2 (because there are a *lot* of parallels in how everything works), but it is not necessary. If you don't have any prior experience with Magento, you would be better off starting fresh on Magento 2.

There is definitely a steep learning curve, but make use of the resources available to you. Here are a few:

- Official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/
- Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development course: https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development
- StackExchange questions and answers: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2
- Alan Storm's excellent developer blog: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Magento 1.x experience is very helpful to learn Magento 2.x, but also agreed with @RyanH's answer that is not compulsory.

Some Good Resource of Magento 2 ( learning pupose )

[Magento 2 Development Blog • Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/)

[Magento 2 Tutorials - Ultimate Free Beginner's online training course](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial)

[Magento 2 module from scratch - Introduction ashsmith.io](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-introduction/)

[Excellencemagentoblog.com](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/)

[Magento 2 Tutorial - MagePlaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/)

[LinkedIn Magento 2 Tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ultimate-magento-2-tutorial-viktor-khliupko)

[Magento 2 Beginner to Advance by - tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-magento-introduction-installation--cms-21969)

[Magento 2 Beginner - creare.co.uk](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento)

[Magento 2 Training Program - Maxime Huran](https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/magento-2-training-2/)

[Basic Magento 2 Blog - belvg.com](http://blog.belvg.com/category/magento-news)

[Basic Magento 2 Blog - Magehit](http://magehit.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial/)

[Magento 2 Blog - Webkul](http://webkul.com/blog/?s=magento%202)

[Magento 2 Basic Course Understandinge](https://understandinge.com/course/magento-2-basics-course/)

[Magento 2 Blog - Magemash](http://magemash.com/news/tag/magento-2/)